# Need to find the list of all countries in Bounding Box

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I have requirement where I need list down all the countries from tow diagonally geo-coordinate  58.75383399335443,-13.411479469299309,35.366463598059575,56.90102053070069

Above I have added two pair of coordinate using that we can form a rectangle and I need list of countries which lies inside the rectangle.

Thanks

Gaurav Singh

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use two coordinates to create a bounding box, then find all counties with that bounding box. This isn't a feature in Bing Maps, but can easily be achieved using a spatial database such as SQL.

County boundary data is typically available as open data. You can upload this data into SQL and then do an intersection test with the database to retrieve the boundaries you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersects-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

It is possible to do all of this within an application/in memory, however, performance won't be great. Here is an example were I did something similar within the browser, but using census blocks limited to individual states: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Census%20block%20group%20analysis